# Why was react-native experimental discontinued?

Tags: react-native

The library was said to be future of Navigation in React-native. I was reading and analysing different navigators. A lot of places suggests that it has been deprecated but none suggested the reason behind.

Comment: The experimental version of navigator deprecated in favor of react-navigation. You can read about it more [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12103).

Comment: Not satisfying, Understood that they are using a new repo. But is that the only reason why they had to deprecate it. Wants to know about the cons and working of the library. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: As it says in the first sentence _Navigator was superseded by NavigationExperimental and finally by React Navigation. To increase the focus on core components and direct PRs to the right place, we may want to deprecate the old navigator libraries._. Facebook wants to concentrate on core features as much as they can and react-navigation is a really good maintained package. NavigationExperimental was experimental so it was not ready for production builds.